# JSONWebTokens in Scalatra

Tags: scala, jwt, scalatra, scalatra-sbt

So I'm trying to secure my web application by using JWT in Scalatra. At the moment I'm using Scentry with both User-Password and RememberMe strategies and my intention is to swap the cookie-based authentication in RememberMe strategy with JWT authentication.

I have found [this implementation](https://github.com/pauldijou/jwt-scala) I can use with json4s ([example](http://pauldijou.fr/jwt-scala/samples/jwt-json4s/)) but I'm not sure of how to include these features in my code. Can I just simply switch the verifications done with cookies in RememberMe for JWT verifications?

Answer (score 1):

In the same repository, which you have provided there are now code examples. You can check this [link](https://github.com/pauldijou/jwt-scala/tree/master/examples/play-angular-standalone).